# Removing QActions from the ui_mainwindow.h file

Tags: qt

My app was started (by someone else) in Qt Designer.  For a number of reasons I've decided to put the main form gui together in C++.  In the designed I deleted all the gui widgets and removed the menu items from the object tree.

Having got the layout how I want it I started adding in the actions to find that they are still declared in the ui_mainwindow.h file.

Is it safe to manually remove the action declarations from this file?  Or is there a way of doing this through Qt designer?

Comment: ui_mainwindow.h is generated file - it should be overwritten after running build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `*.ui` file in the designer. In the lower right corner you'll see `Action Editor`. Actions can be deleted from there.

[image]

Comment: Easy as that!  Thank you.